# Count how many unique values there are in each row of a matrix (2d array) in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, multidimensional-array, unique

I have a 2d array and I would like find how many unique values there is in each row. For example:

```
arr = np.array([[3,4,4,4,3,4], 
                [4,4,4,4,4,4], 
                [3,3,3,2,3,2],
                [2,3,3,1,2,2]])
```

Then the output that I desire to obtain would be:

```
res = np.array([2,1,2,3])
```

Because there are two uniques values in first row, one unique value in second row, two in third row and three in fourth row.

How can I achieve this? Using `np.unique` and `np.bincounts` I was not able.

Comment: Have you tried row by row `np.unique`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate the length of a set for each row.

```
[len(set(x)) for x in arr]
```

Answer (score 2):

For a vectorial approach you could use:

```
res = (np.diff(np.sort(arr))!=0).sum(axis=1)+1

# or
res = arr.shape[1]-(np.diff(np.sort(arr))==0).sum(axis=1)
```

Or with [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) and [`nunique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nunique.html):

```
import pandas as pd

res = pd.DataFrame(arr).nunique(axis=1).to_numpy()
```

Output: `array([2, 1, 2, 3])`

Answer (score 0):

I'd apply a function along the `axis=1` that counts the unique values:

```
np.apply_along_axis(lambda a: len(np.unique(a)), axis=1, arr=arr)
```